# R mlogit package: system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, mlogit

I am trying to analyze a choice experiment for a homework:

```
 $ id: num [1:1944] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ set          : num [1:1944] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ option       : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ choice: num [1:1944] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ asc          : Factor [1:1944] "1" "1" "0" "1" ...
 $ REC: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 2 1 3 3 1 3 3 1 2 ...
 $ BDV: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 ...
 $ SITE: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 3 ...
 $ COST: num [1:1944] 1000 2500 0 2500 1000 0 1500 2500 0 2500 ...
```

So the CE have 3 attributes (REC, BDV and SITE) each one has three levels (0, 1 and 3). Thus, each person had choice sets, each set have 3 options (0, 1 and 3).

I need to do a Multinomial logistic regression, so I used the 'mlogit' package.

My model is this:

```
test.mlogit2<- mlogit.data(Choicedata2, choice = "choice", shape = "long",  alt.var = "option", id.var = "id")
Clogit2 <- mlogit(choice~REC+BDV+SITE+COST,data=test.mlogit2, reflevel = 3)
summary(Clogit2)
```

and I have this error:

```
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.06743e-21
```

The most common answer I have read is that it is a multicollinearity problem, so I tested removing variables and effectively it doesn't give me the error removing the REC variable. The problem is that I made the function only with the REC variable and it gives me the same error, but testing the other attributes alone doesn't give me the error, so I don't think it's a multicollinearity problem.

```
test.mlogit2<- mlogit.data(Choicedata2, choice = "choice", shape = "long",  alt.var = "option", id.var = "id")
    
Clogit2 <- mlogit(choice~REC,data=test.mlogit2, reflevel = 3)
summary(Clogit2)
Error in solve.default(-object$hessian[selcoef, selcoef]) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.95733e-16
```

---

REC:

```
table(test.mlogit2$choice,test.mlogit2$REC)
                      0   1   2
              FALSE 485 435 376
              TRUE  163 213 272

det(t(as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC)) %*% as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC))
[1] 3240
```

BDV:

```
table(test.mlogit2$choice,test.mlogit2$BDV)
                  0   1   2
          FALSE 955 156 185
          TRUE  341 163 144
    
det(t(as.matrix(test.mlogit2$BDV)) %*% as.matrix(test.mlogit2$BDV))
[1] 1635
```

SITE:

```
table(test.mlogit2$choice,test.mlogit2$SITE)      
              0   1   2
      FALSE 993 146 157
      TRUE  303 188 157
    
det(t(as.matrix(test.mlogit2$SITE)) %*% as.matrix(test.mlogit2$SITE))
[1] 1590
```

However, the error appear only with REC (alone or with the other attributes)

Comment: Could you do a `table(test.mlogit2$choice,test.mlogit2$REC)` and share the result?

Comment: Also you could share the result of `det(as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC))` to check how close to zero the determinant is? If it very close to zero, it won't be invertible.

Comment: sure, thanks!!! @FightMilk

Comment: You are trying to compute the determinant of an array of 1944 values.  It doesn't have a determinant, as the message correctly says.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your answer, can I define the determinant? or what can I do?

Comment: My bad, you need to try `det(t(as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC)) %*% as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC))`. Basically what I was trying to check was that the matrix $X'X$ is invertible or not (I am pretty sure in this case its not). You can try adding a `tol` parameter to the `mlogit` function and see if it works, e.g. `mlogit(choice~REC,data=test.mlogit2, reflevel = 3,tol = 1e-17)`

Comment: @FightMilk no problem, I'm glad that was just a mistake :D `det(t(as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC)) %*% as.matrix(test.mlogit2$REC)) [1] 3240` and yes, I tried with adding tol, but it does not work =////

Comment: @FightMilk Using `as.matrix` is inappropriate, because `REC` is a *factor,* not a numeric variable.  At the very least you should be examining the *model matrix,* which `R` will compute with `model.matrix` and associated functions.